# Problems getting IIS to work

Tags: visual-studio, iis

I have installed Visual Studio 2017 on a Windows 10 PC. I thought this would also install IIS Express. However, when I browse to localhost I get a localhost refused to connect error. The same error occurs when I try to browse to the http://localhost:49247 url for my solution in visual studio. I have tried installing IIS Express 10 separately and also tried turning on the IIS features in windows 10, but with the same results.

I've also tried changing the port number and deleting applicationhost.config, as suggested elsewhere on this site, but these didn't work for me either.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The description above is useless. Run VSPDiag and show the information it reports, https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/vs-diagnostics.html

Comment: @LexLi - installed Jexus Manager and ran diagnostics as suggested. Output was as follows `0 project(s) are detected.
Zero or multiple C# project files are detected. Currently VSDiag only supports a single C# project.`

Comment: @LexLi - Jexus Manager helped me identify a problem in my applicationhost.config file and I can now connect to my Umbraco installation on localhost:8080 rather than localhost:49247. Now I've just got to sort out a database connection string issue, but that's a different problem. Many thanks for pointing me to your useful program.

Comment: You should post your findings as an answer and accept it.